# Non recursive provably total functions

Tags: number-theory, first-order-logic, recursion, computability, peano-axioms

It is provable that every primitive recursive function is total in 1st order PA. Some non primitive recursive functions are also provably total in PA.

Can we show that a function is totally provable in PA but it doesn't has a recursive definition  ? Somehow we need to diagonalize over all the provably total recursive functions , but that function should be uncomputable since turning machines can only compute total and recursive functions,  yet one could show that the diagonalized function is representable in PA and also is provably total...

Comment: Ackermann would be non-Primitive recursive provably total, but it certainly would be recursively defined ......

Comment: @DanDoel so ackermann isn't the right example....

Comment: I see. So you want an example of a function that PA proves total, but isn't even μ-recursive.

Comment: @DanDoel can you check the last line written in this subsection ' Relation to recursively defined functions ', the one in brackets for which citation is needed... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function#Relation_to_recursively_defined_functions                       that's what i am asking